# Parse img and html codes with dom (php)

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have a code that parsing img and texts. Run the code in php file. It's just showing img src, abc, img src, dfe. And my code is not regular. img tags are may be with link.

I want to parse img and next **html**. Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => http://www.whatever.com
            [text] =>  abc
    <br>
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a></div>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => http://goingnowhere.com
            [text] =>  def
    <br>
    <h3>title 2</h3>
    <div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a>

    bla bla bla

    </div>
        )

)
```

How can I do this? My current code:

```
<?php $sample_html = '
<img src="http://www.whatever.com" alt="" />
abc
<br>
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a></div>
<img src="http://goingnowhere.com" alt="">
def
<br>
<h3>title 2</h3>
<div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a>

bla bla bla

</div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($sample_html);

$data = array();
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
$data[] = array(
'src' => $image->getAttribute('src'),
'text' => trim($image->nextSibling->textContent),
);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data); ?>
```

Comment: `trim($image->nextSibling->textContent)` will only give the text in the next item, looks as though you want all of the HTML until the next `<img>` tag - is there any limit as to when to stop extracting the HTML after the `<img>` tag?

Comment: I need img tag, abc and other html contents. img, and html in data. My html code is not regular. I need just parse img and html. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath to iterate through all nodes & retrieve data withing two img tags.

```
<?php $sample_html = '
<img src="http://www.whatever.com" alt="" />
abc
<br>
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a></div>
<img src="http://goingnowhere.com" alt="">
def
<br>
<h3>title 2</h3>
<div class="content">content <a href="link">my link</a>

bla bla bla

</div>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHtml($sample_html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$snippet = '';
$arr = array();
$count = $xpath->query('//img')->length;
//loop through all img tags
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

    $node = $xpath->query('//img')->item($i);
    $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');//first image src

    while ($node = $node->nextSibling) {

      if (get_class($node) != 'DOMElement') {
        continue;
      }

      if ($node->tagName  == 'img') {
        $snippet .= $dom->saveXML($node);
        $arr[] = array(
            'src'=>$img_src,
            'content'=>$snippet
        );
        $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');//last img src
        $snippet = '';
        break;
      }
      $snippet .= $dom->saveXML($node);

    }
}
//fill last img data
$arr[] = array('src'=>$img_src,'content'=>$snippet);
```

Comment: How can I append img and htmls to data and use them separately? (like at my code) [0]=>(["img"]=>"<img src='link.jpg' />,["html"]=>"html codes")

Comment: It helped BUT it didn't echo "abc" and "def". :) I need texts too. Can you make a try again?

Comment: then comment `if (get_class($node) != 'DOMElement') ` this condition, it ignores the non-dom elements

Comment: I deleted that 3 lines and I got this error: "Notice: Undefined property: DOMText::$tagName in line 36." Can you look and change the code again? Thanks. :)